# Why is Jiraiya’s headband different from that of other Leaf Shinobi?

Tags: naruto

[image]

[image]

The Headbands Ninjas Wear Symbolize who they are Loyal to.
Then why Jiraiya, a leaf shinobi has different headband?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol on [Jiraiya's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya) headband translate to

> "oil" (油, abura)

The reason why Jirayia wears this symbol on this headband rather than the leaf symbol is to show his affiliation with the toads on [Mount Myōboku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku)

> He often carried a large scroll on his back, and had a tattoo on his left palm, and he wore a horned forehead protector with the kanji for "oil" (油, abura), which denoted his affiliation with Mount Myōboku.

Answer (score -2):

He also probably wore that instead of the leaf symbol because he would go on reconnaissance missions where he has to be undercover and keep his identity a secret.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.